# Calculate Optical Flow using foreground mask

Tags: opencv, background, opticalflow

I am using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() to calculate Optical Flow. However, instead of using good features to track, I am now using background subtraction to get the foreground image mask and pass it to the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(). But I am not very sure how to pass foreground mask directly to calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(). Do I have to scan through the foreground mask and store all the foreground pixels to a vector then pass it to calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()?

Is there other solution where we can combine background subtraction and optical flow efficiently?

Comment: Not sure whether you can create a sparse mat from your mask efficiently. Othrrwise storing each foreground point manually in a vector is the method i use when I need mask pixels. BUT keep in mind that your foreground pixel might not be well trackable

Comment: Depending on how you compute your foreground you can integrate the vector filling in that process!

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing as you mentioned. But sometimes, the foreground gets distortion. So I decided to sampling and always take the fixed the number of foreground pixels. I am not sure is there any other ideas better than this?